# ActionMailer with Cloud9 > Devise > Heroku > GoDaddy Results in OpenTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, actionmailer

I used Cloud9 to develop my site and eventually deployed it to Heroku, then connected that to a GoDaddy domain I have. I also purchased an Office 365 email from GoDaddy.

I'm trying to figure out how to send an automatic email after a user signs up to my site. I use the Devise gem to handle user registration. I followed the RailsCast #206 (Action Mailer in Rails) to the T and have looked at many different tutorials and forums to see if I could get any help, but to no avail. The user sign up works until there is a long delay and I eventually receive the following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30518ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):
```

Other times I have received an `EOFError`. My login information is working because I do not receive a connection error.

Here is a snippet in my `user.rb` model:

```
after_create :welcome_send

def welcome_send
  UserMailer.signup_confirmation(self).deliver
end
```

This is `user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => "info@my1040academy.com"

  def signup_confirmation(user)
    @greeting = "Hi"
    @user = user
    attachments["512.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/512.png")
    mail(:to => "#{user.first_name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

`setup_mail.rb` in `config/init`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.office365.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "my1040academy.com",
  :user_name            => ENV['my full email address'],
  :password             => ENV['my password'],
  :authentication       => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "my1040academy.com"
```

`signup_confirmation.text.erb`:

```
UserMailer#signup_confirmation

<%= @greeting %>, find me in app/views/user_mailer/signup_confirmation.text.erb

Welcome, <%= @user.email %>.
```

This one has me stumped. Any help would be very much appreciated!